# Filling an inputTextArea with content from multiple selectOneMenus and buttons

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to build a small UI which will offer the user the posibility to write some math formulas in an easier way(hence the UI) and be able to save them to a .txt (or something similar) file.

For example: I have 3 selectboxes which offer a variety of options, some buttons which represent math operations and an inputTextArea. So far I've managed to link selected content from each selectOneMenu and from a few inputText's and concatenate them with what i need and write the created math formulas to a .txt file.

Now I want to offer the user the possibility to see the formula he is writing(by selecting content and pressing buttons) as he is doing it. So far I've been trying to do that using an inputTextArea but the best I managed was to transfer the selected content from **only one** selectOneMenu to the textArea and after that all my attempts to add every action the user makes to the text area have failed(someone suggested using `<h:panelGroup>` but I got nowhere with that, I tried to combine all the beans I used to fill the menus into one bean and somehow go from there , but that didn't work either).

A sample of the JSF part I've been working on so far, with 2 selectboxes and the TextArea:

```html
<h:outputText value="Formula Name"></h:outputText>
<h:inputText value="#{output.formulaName}" id="formulaName"></h:inputText>              
<br /><br />

The formula so far:
<h:inputTextarea value="#{output.propertyReferenceValue}"></h:inputTextarea>
<br/><br/><br/>

Property1:
<h:selectOneMenu  value ="#{output.propertyReferenceValue}" id="selectTwo"  
    valueChangeListener="#{output.propertyReferenceValueChanged}" onchange="submit()">
    <f:selectItems value="#{property.propertyReference}"/>              
</h:selectOneMenu>
<br/><br/>
Property2:         
<h:selectOneMenu value ="#{output.property2ReferenceValue}" id="selectThree"  
    valueChangeListener="#{output.property2ReferenceChangedValue}" onchange="submit()">
    <f:selectItems value="#{property2.property2Refference}" />            
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

PS. I'm very new to JSF(started about 2 days ago) so I will appreciate even being pointed to some documentation which might cover this or similar problems.

Comment: Those `valueChangeListener`s are basically hacks. You seem not to be interested in a value change, but only in the submitted value. Before posting an answer, I'd like to know if you're using JSF 1.x or 2.x. Posting the both listener methods would also be helpful to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve with the input and output.

Comment: I am using JSF 2.0.  I don't have the last version of the app on this computer(posting from laptop now) but the listener methods looked something like this:    public void propertyReferenceValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent e){
            propertyReferenceValue=e.getNewValue().toString();         
        }                                                                      The other listener was similar. Hope i managed to clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically abusing the `valueChangeListener` here. You're not exactly interested in the value change (i.e. you aren't interested in **both** the old and new value), you're only interested in the submitted value. This was tolerated in JSF 1.x when you didn't/can't/won't use an ajax based component library. There are (rather complicated) ways to fix your particular problem with the `valueChangeListener`, but in JSF 2.x, which ships with builtin ajax capabilities, this really can't be done that way anymore. You should rather use the `<f:ajax>` tag to introduce asynchronous submits and partial updates.

Rewrite your view as follows:

```html
Formula name:
<h:inputText value="#{output.formulaName}" id="formulaName" />
<br/><br/>

The formula so far:
<h:inputTextarea id="formula" value="#{output.propertyReferenceValue}#{output.property2ReferenceValue}"></h:inputTextarea>
<br/><br/>

Property1:
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{output.propertyReferenceValue}" id="selectTwo">
    <f:selectItems value="#{property.propertyReference}"/>
    <f:ajax render="formula" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<br/><br/>

Property2:         
<h:selectOneMenu value ="#{output.property2ReferenceValue}" id="selectThree">
    <f:selectItems value="#{property2.property2Refference}" />            
    <f:ajax render="formula" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

That's all. Your `#{output}` bean should be put in the view scope by `@ViewScoped`. No addidional listener methods are necessary. Only if you ever want to manipulate the values before displaying it, then you need an ajax listener. E.g.

```html
Formula name:
<h:inputText value="#{output.formulaName}" id="formulaName" />
<br/><br/>

The formula so far:
<h:inputTextarea id="formula" value="#{output.formula}"></h:inputTextarea>
<br/><br/>

Property1:
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{output.propertyReferenceValue}" id="selectTwo">
    <f:selectItems value="#{property.propertyReference}"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{output.calculateFormula}" render="formula" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<br/><br/>

Property2:         
<h:selectOneMenu value ="#{output.property2ReferenceValue}" id="selectThree">
    <f:selectItems value="#{property2.property2Refference}" />            
    <f:ajax listener="#{output.calculateFormula}" render="formula" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with e.g. (this kickoff example does a simple concatenation on comma, you've however the full freedom to build the `formula` value the way you want):

```
public void calculateFormula() {
    formula = propertyReferenceValue + ", " + property2ReferenceValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. First thing tomorrow I will make the necessary changes. Since this is the second JSF issue you've helped me on, could you recommned any good reading material/tutorials related to JSF 2.0? I've been doing every tutorial i can get my hands on (as well as reading through other people's JSF related issues), but those are mostly easy ones. Probably the one i got the most out of was http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Mkyong.com is a good resource. But those articles are pretty high level and only shows *how* to approach X, not the *why*. Perhaps you will find my last blog article useful: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html

Comment: Just as a small update, your advice worked fine:) It just took me about an hour , because i forgot to add "<h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces"/> " to the JSF head. Thank you again.

Comment: You should have used `<h:head>` instead of `<head>`. It would then be auto-included.